# Read a text file line by line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a text file like this:

```
User:root
Password:root123
```

I need to access this text file through JavaScript line by line, and store in an array, so that I can split each value in that array with `:`

I tried many ways but it didn’t work.

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var tmpDoc, re=/^(.+)$/gm, arr=[], oP, arrSplit=[], arrSpl=[];
  if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
    if(xmlHttp.status === 200){
      alert("AS");
      tmpDoc = xmlHttp.responseText;    
      arrSpl = tmpDoc.split(",");
      var arrGlobalHost = arrSpl[0].split(':');
      var arrGlobalUser = arrSpl[1].split(':');
      var arrGlobalPass = arrSpl[2].split(':');
      strGlobalHost = arrGlobalHost[1];
      strGlobalUser = arrGlobalUser[1];
      strGlobalPass = arrGlobalPass[1];
      xmlHttp=null;
    }
  }
}; 
xmlHttp.open("POST", fileName, true); // Use POST to prevent use of cached file
xmlHttp.send();
```

I called this on button click event but I am not getting the output for the first time. As ready state is maintained only after loading the page on first time I need to do it on loading the page for first time itself.

Comment: is the file accessible through the web? if not javascript cannot access it. If it is accessible you should research AJAX

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far

Comment: JavaScript is forbidden from accessing a computer's file system (in case you were wondering). You can access a hosted file (served by something like Apache, ngix or lighttpd) using an XHttpRequest (or AJAX if you must). This will deliver the contents of the file as text to your JavaScript code, which you can then manipulate as you see fit.

Comment: @SparroHawk mostly correct, if you access in a folder an index.html that calls local data, it can have access. (tested to make sure with one of my git projects) by accessing the index.html directly in a folder on my machine (not through git)  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it in my own technichue
I just edited the text file (config.txt)  by comma seperated

```
User:root,
Password:root123
```

I also added a hidden field called user to take the response of file which is read through ajax
Then my code I have written is as follows:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();// Specify HTTP GET by default and supply the relative url  
xmlHttp.open("POST", "config.txt", false);  // Start a synchronous AJAX request and wait for the response 
xmlHttp.send(null); 
var result = document.getElementById('user').value;
var result= xmlHttp.responseText; 
var arrSplt = new Array;
arrSplt = result.split(',');//seperating commas
var arrSplittedCredHost = new Array;var arrSplittedCredUser = new Array;
var arrSplittedCredPass = new Array;
arrSplittedCredHost = arrSplt[0].split(':');
arrSplittedCredUser = arrSplt[1].split(':');
arrSplittedCredPass = arrSplt[2].split(':');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows -- **JScript + ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx

```
var fso, f1, ts;
var ForWriting = 2;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
fso.CreateTextFile ("c:\\test1.txt");
f1 = fso.GetFile("c:\\test1.txt");
ts = f1.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, true);
while (!ts.AtEndOfStream()) {
   var line = ts.ReadLine();
}
```

In Other -- **Node.js + "File System"**

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readable = fs.createReadStream('sample.txt', {start: 90, end: 99});
readable.on('data', function(chunk) {
  console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
});
```

Comment: I am not understanding var fs = require('fs');

Comment: http://nodejs.org/
Node.js is a server-side platform built on JavaScript runtime.
You can't read any file from OS if your code is running in a browser, see a comment by SparoHawk.

Answer (score 0):

Taken directory from the web

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
   $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
});
});
</script>
 </head>
```

```
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>
```

Advice, google search